# Why are  Agents & Managers considered poor O-O design

Tags: oop, object

Back in the early '90s I participated in the design and implementation of a system that included lots of "Agent" classes.  The system worked well and was reasonably maintainable.  Now I'm in arguments with folks in a new work environment who make the claim that "Objects should be nouns".  Are there good articles around explaining why Agents are a Bad Idea?  And what distinguishes an Agent from an Object in more detail (I get the general idea, but what specifically is deprecated?)

Preferably not whole books:  I just now started reading Bertrand Meyer's book on Object-Oriented Software Construction, and it's gonna take some time to get through that.

Per comments from Tomasz and Niko, I changed the subject line (from asking for pointers to articles) and now invite people to answer directly rather than give pointers to articles.

Comment: Look how much hype is around [tag:akka] these days (and for good!) Just choose the best tools you can. PS: voting to close as not constructive.

Comment: It's really discouraging to have you vote to close as non-constructive.  I deliberately didn't ask people to weigh in here, I asked for pointers to articles.

Comment: SO is generally not a good place for lists of recommandations. You should consider rephrasing your question and directly ask "(why) are agents a bad idea" here instead of asking for literature about that topic.

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia says

> Agent-oriented programming (AOP) is a programming paradigm where the
>   construction of the software is centered around the concept of
>   software agents. In contrast to object-oriented programming which has
>   objects (providing methods with variable parameters) at its core
>   (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_object)

However I don't think at AOP as separated from OOP I personally worked with JADE(http://jade.tilab.com/, which is one of the most famous framework implementing the FIPA standards (http://www.fipa.org) and as far as I remember in JADE agents can own objects (as instances of java classes) that can exploit to perform complex functions. In this sense the concept of agent is similar to the concept of active object (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_object). The main differences are that Agents publish a description of the services they provide in a yellow pages registry and are capable of communicating by means of shared languages (possibly based on onthologies). Also mobility can be provided so that a running agent may migrate to a different device preserving its execution state. However such complexity can be implemented on the top of the Thread thus extending the OO paradigm and not being in contrast with it.

the concept of agent was first used by Yoav Shoham within his Artificial Intelligence studies, in 1990.

In this link http://www.infor.uva.es/~cllamas/MAS/AOP-Shoham.pdf you can find an excerpt of a Shoham pubblication in which he says

> whereas OOP proposes viewing a computational system as made up of
>   modules that are able to communicate with one another and that have
>   individual ways of handling incoming messages, AOP specializes the
>   framework by fixing the state (now called mental state) of the modules
>   (now called agents) to consist of precisely defined components called
>   beliefs (including beliefs about the world, about rhemselves, and abour one anorher), 
>   capabiliries, choices, and possibly orher similar norions. A
>   compurarion consists of rhese agents' informing, requesting, offering,
>   accepting, rejecting, competing, and assisting one another. This idea
>   is borrowed directly from the speech act literature (Grice 1989;
>   Searle 1969;Austin 1962).

The key word is that AOP **specializes** the OOP framework. So as I said it extends OOP (not necessarely in a good way though). I guess you may want to use this kind of architecture, which is very nice to design and implement, when you deal with computational intensive systems that may need to scale to cope with highly variable amount of tasks. In other cases AOP may be overkilling but that is up to your designer/architect sensitivity.

Comment: I'm resisting the urge to downvote merely for starting the response with "Wikipedia says..."

Comment: I guess there is nothing wrong in quoting someone. The important thing is to always reference the source as I actually did. Why don't you like it?

Comment: Because Wikipedia is an unauthenticated source for nearly anything , written by anyone, with virtually no accountability for its accuracy. Don't mind a quote, but I don't like Wikipedia.

Comment: I see your point though I just wanted to quote both what is the folk understanding of AOP (wikipedia) and the Shoham's point of view

Answer (score 4):

OOP is all about encapsulating state and associated behaviour together.

Agents, managers and helpers tend to have no state; they are usually just a bunch of methods that operate on some input data. Such code also has an abundance of getters and setters, because the data objects are too dumb to do anything by themselves. This is not OOP, it is procedural programming.

Good OO design revolves around telling objects what to do instead of asking them for data and then doing something with it. Anytime you call a getter, ask yourself if you could have the object directly perform the action instead. For example, instead of doing:

```
account.setBalance(account.getBalance() + x);
```

try doing:

```
account.deposit(x);
```

Note that there are situations where one might use agent-like objects, in the form of strategies or service objects, but done properly, they do not break encapsulation.

Comment: Why do you say agents don't have state and are just bunch of methods. That is actually wrong. AOP is the very opposite. Agents are aimed at being autonomous, possibly intelligent (obviously in terms of AI), entities capable of performing complex operations and cooperate to cope with more complex one (or to properly scale the overall functionalities when the amount of work increases). They have states and they do not just consist of a bunch of methods as they communicate by means of messages with specific languages conform complex protocols and ontologies (see http://www.fipa.org)

Comment: @Silli: My answer was not about AOP agents at all (nor did the OP specifically mention AOP). In the context of "agents & managers", an "agent class" is usually one that performs actions on behalf of another object, and from my experience, this tends to lead to separation of data and behaviour.

Comment: In my experience an object with performs an action on behalf of another object is a "delegate". An agent is actually more.

Comment: @Silli: I'm not debating that "agents are actually more". But since agent is such a generic term (outside of AOP), and since the OP also mentioned "managers", I'm simply saying I've seen similar "agents" that contain logic that should rightly be part of another object -- such agents end up doing work that another object should be doing. That's totally different from delegation, which is simply forwarding calls to another object.